# simple recursive function error - java.lang.StackOverFlow error - output exceeds cut off limit

Tags: scala

I am practicing scala's simple recursive function. This is from a book

```
def calculatePower(x:Int, y:Int): Long = {

     if (x>=1)
         x*calculatePower(x,y-1)

     else 1

  }


calculatePower(2,2)
```

Comment: you're checking x but reducing y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *method* stack overflows because it doesn't terminate and the stack frames accumulates until there is no more room.

`if (x>=1) x*calculatePower(x,y-1)` You test if `x` is greater or equal to 1 but in the recursive call you only decrement `y`!

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `x` but you are decrementing `y`. That means your base-case will never be reached.